# MySQL string to date brings all rows with the same year

Tags: mysql

I have a table that the data is a text in the format: 05/07/2019 (dd/mm/yyyy).
When I try to convert it to a date with
`str_to_date(date_field,'%d/%m/%y')` 
I get the response in the format 2020-06-21 (yyyy-mm-dd). But the problem is that in the result all of the years are 2020 though this isn't the actual sitatuion.
Is there a way to solve this or do I need to recreate the DB with the date to be in date format?

Comment: Please add sample data which helps to explain your current problem.  To your latter question, yes, you should avoid storing dates as text (unless you are using SQLite).

Comment: If you are going to store dates, use a proper date type  to do it, never store dates as strings

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the format dd/mm/yyyy you need to use capital Y

- %Y   Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
- %y   Year as a numeric, 2-digit value

So, in your case, you should use `str_to_date(date_field,'%d/%m/%Y')` because when you use y, it is taking only the first two digits for the year.

And, as I said in my comment (and Tim also said) if you are storing dates in a RDBMS, you should use ALWAYS proper date/datetime data types.